# As many / as many as

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

> ______ thousand species of butterflies have been identified.

Which is the correct phrase to use here ? I tried to find answer googling but internet is flooded with *many* vs *much* differences, couldn't find any site where they have explained the usage of *as many* vs *as many as*.

Comment: It certainly isn't *much*. *Many* would be most appropriate; perhaps best if the phrasing were this: "Many thousands of species of butterflies have been identified."

Comment: The construction ***as many as** N [plural noun]* is an idiom implying that (a) the exact value of ***N*** is uncertain, (b) the speaker thinks ***N*** is surprisingly large (and expects the audience to feel the same way), and (c) the *actual* number is probably slightly less than ***N***, rather than slightly more (the number chosen for ***N*** is usually the largest the speaker can get away with without obviously exaggerating things). Unless you specifically want all those associations, follow @ArrowCase's advice and stick with plain ***many***.

Comment: ...I've just Googled to discover that there are [*17,500 species of butterflies*](https://www.si.edu/Encyclopedia_SI/nmnh/buginfo/butterfly.htm). It would be pushing it a bit, and you'd probably be wise to include the word ***may*** as a "hedge", but you could say *As many as 20,000 species of butterfly **may** have been identified* (once we collate all the data).

Answer (score 1):

There are a few alternatives here:

> As many as **a** thousand species of butterflies have been identified.

(ie. at most 1000  -- probably slightly less than 1000)

> Many thousand species of butterflies have been identified.

or

> Many thousand**s of** species of butterflies have been identified.

(ie. not just one thousand. The number of thousands is many.)

> As many thousand**s of** species of butterflies have been identified **...** .

(ie. Because the number of species is many thousand ...)